# Error: "The network name cannot be found" during In-place upgrade from CRM 2015 to CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

During the "In-place upgrade" procedure from CRM 2015 to CRM 2016 (on premise)
I receive the following error message:

```
Error| System.Exception: Action Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallSqlClrHelperAction failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The network name cannot be found.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.Helpers.CopyDatabaseFile(String sourcePath, String sourceFileName, Boolean isBuildEnvironment, String 

sqlServerName, String destinationFilePath, String destinationFileName, String& copyDestinationPath)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallSqlClrHelperAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---, Error, AbortRetryIgnore, Option1
```

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like based on the call stack that the user you are performing the upgrade with likely is missing Local administrator privileges on the SQL server.  If the installing user has the sysadmin SQL role and is a local administrator on the SQL server, I suspect you will get past this error.